# Retrieving 'Id' value from requesting page

Tags: asp.net

HTML for the issue

Click here

Click here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `id` attribute of the clicked link will not be passed to the server when the request is made. You could include it the URL, like this:

```
<li><a href="nextpage.aspx?id=1" id="1">Click here</a></li>
<li><a href="nextpage.aspx?id=2" id="2">Click here</a></li>
```

And then on the server side, you would use either `Request.QueryString["id"]` (C#) or `Request.QueryString("id")` (VB.NET) to to get the value specified in the URL.

Or possibly use some kind of JavaScript based solution, but without more details it would be hard to say exactly how that would look.

Comment: pswq, that is exactly what i'm trying to avoid.  I would like to hide the parameter in 'id' attribute but looks like that wont work since id is not sent to the server like you said.

Comment: @user2844121 Is there any particular reason why you're trying to avoid that?

Comment: And then use Request.QueryString("id") or Request.QueryString["id"] to get the value

Comment: @user2844121 You'll have to use a button with a form if you want to send the value as POST instead of GET.

Comment: @the_lotus Good point. I should have included that information in my answer.

Comment: because i don't like that the id=2 is shown in the url. The thing is that this is already written as type ='get' and i don't want to change that part to post.  I would like to keep it as 'get' but come up with a way of hiding the parameter from the url.

Comment: @user2844121 Unfortunately, no. I don't see any way to do that. You could do some funky tricks like wrapping the page in an `iframe` so the user doesn't *see* the URL or like I said, some JS-based solution using an XHR to make the request and post the result to the page (see [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) for some ideas).

Comment: ok so looks like the best and most practical way would be to switch method to post...